# google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID that you don't appear to have access to

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

In Firebase Option Android Studio when I click on "connect to firebase" I am getting the following error.

> "google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID that you don't appear to have access to. Request access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection process.

I don't know how to request to access and delete. What should I do?

Comment: have you created project with same package name on firebase console and downloaded `google-services.json`?

Comment: yes! package name is same on both sides.

Comment: open that json file and check whether all data is available there and it's correct or not

Answer (score 44):

This error will occur if you are signed in to Android Studio and the Firebase Console with different accounts.

In Android Studio, click on the small profile icon in the upper right corner to see your sign-in account.  Do the same for the Firebase Console tab of your browser.  If they are different, sign out and sign in to make them the same.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I had to navigate to the web console:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/

and add my app as a project manually:

[image: firebase console]

After clicking "ADD FIREBASE" it worked.

Comment: Thanks for saving me some time! Wanted to note you get that dialog by clicking the "Import Google Project" button on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete "google-services.json" file in "app" folder of your project and re-connect your app to Firebase with Assistant

Answer (score 2):

Reason:

- if you are signed in to Android Studio and the Firebase Console with different accounts
- Or your JSON file is corrupted

Solution :

- Use same account for Studio and console.
- Delete the corrupted JSON and use Studio plugin to create the project, it will automatically handle the corner cases

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I had a wrong "google-service.json" file in my project.
(I signed in to Android Studio ＆ Firebase Console)

If you are like me, you need this.

① delete all "google-service" file. You can easily find it by [Ctrl + shift + n] and put 
  the file name in.

② Go to Firebase Console → Setting → App setting → app card below, now you can find 　"goole-service.json" file that is customized for your project. Download it.

③ Copy the new file and　paste it in your Project. (Project →　app → here!!!)

④ Go to Firebase assistant and click "connect to Firebase"

Answer (score 0):

In my case my URL of my main activity was different from that of my `googleServices.json` file. I will advise you to just copy from your `googleServices.json` file and paste in your `MainActivity.java` (Make sure both URLs are exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

> `\appname\.idea\modules\app\google-services.json`
> Delete this file in your project folder first.

In my case, I already had this file in my project files as I changed my package name, and I was trying the add the `google-services.json` file for the second time. And I was getting this error: -

```
> A config file "something\google-services.json" was found, but it
> indicates a project ID that you dont appear to have access to. Request
> access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection
> process.
```