# Android Studio Can't Connect Firebase Assistant

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-assistant

I am trying to connect to Firebase from Android Studio Assistance but getting following error despite having internet connection.

Firebase
A config file "G:\ANDROID\GoFishing\app\google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID "gofishing-149406" that you don't appear to have access to. Request access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection process.

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty clear, have you checked that the data in the configuration file is correct?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42105091/4815718

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-services.json" was found, but it indicates a project ID that you don't appear to have access to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42105091/google-services-json-was-found-but-it-indicates-a-project-id-that-you-dont-ap)

Answer (score 1):

just Delete that config and go again to firebase console and download a new file and make sure that you have given the access to the project if done problem solved if not make sure that you are not usinfg the the package which was already integrated and restricted access for another apps if so create a a new package and do the same process 
if it wont help 
just delete that file (config) and go to assistant and click on connect to fire base and give all the credentials and give the new name to package and go with it every thing runs properly

hope it will hep you for sure

Answer (score 1):

Just delete "google-services.json" file in "app" folder of your project and reconnect your app to Firebase with Assistant

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because the account I used to login to Android Studio (the account in the most top right) that was not the account I created the firebase account with.
As soon as I logged in to my firebase account in android studio it asked to sync and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error if you have open different accounts between Android Studio and Firebase. Because the Firebase assistant attempts to contact the Firebase service with your account registered in Android Studio. You can resolve this error by selecting the Add account option in Android Studio.